# how can we display the field in image or pdf format

Tags: 7, nodes, files, media

I have a `Content Type` as `Article` with fields `Title`, `Article Content` and `Tags`.

When a user sees a `Article`, then how can we display `Article Content`  in Image or pdf format.
And `Title` and `Tags` will be in default state.

How can we convert Text into image or pdf. Is there any module or any hook to implement this.

Comment: Maybe this [module](https://drupal.org/project/textimage) is related to your question. Or this [PHP class](http://www.fpdf.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are the some instructions to be manualled

1) First need to install 
     [Cufon module](http://drupal.org/project/cufon)

2) Enable it and set permission as mention on above link

3) Download cufon-yui.js and place it in any subfolder under:

```
* current theme folder
* sites/all/modules/cufon/
* sites/all/libraries/cufon/
```

below link to download cufon-yui.js

http://cufon.shoqolate.com/js/cufon-yui.js?v=1.09i

4] Generate a font definition and upload it in any of these folders:

```
* current theme folder
* sites/<your site>/libraries/cufon-fonts/
* sites/all/libraries/cufon-fonts/
```

below link to generate the custom font you want to display

http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/

Once you generate and save it to above directories as mention

5] Now goto admin/config/media/cufon

and some css selectors as

```
  `.cufon_selector` and select any font type from the dropdown and enable it
```

Note: you can give .(dot) and # (hash) with name is must

And if you want to other one you can more number of fonts

[image]

6) Now Save configuration

7) Now goto you site directory
     choose you theme directory

```
 `theme->themename->templates`
```

In this select and copy `node.tpl.php` and paste it and rename with your **content type** you want to display

for example : I have content type : `articles`

so `node--articles.tpl.php`

8) Now open `node--articles.tpl.php` or your `node--yourcontentype.tpl.php`

9) Find the

```
<div class="content clearfix"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
<?php
// We hide the comments and links now so that we can render them later.
hide($content['comments']);
hide($content['links']);
print render($content);
?>
</div>
```

And make some edit

```
<div class="content clearfix"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
<?php
// We hide the comments and links now so that we can render them later.
hide($content['comments']);
hide($content['links']);

echo "<div class='vegur_one'>";
print render($content);
echo "</div>";
?>
</div>
```

As i have created `.vegur_one` just add

```
echo "<div class='vegur_one'>";
print render($content);
echo "</div>";
```

10) Now flush the cache and refresh and enjoy it..

Comment: Excellent, atlast found... And is there any way out with pdf files.